# Why set_userdata() doesn't work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, xampp

I'm Using codeigniter framework and i'm having a problem with a session.. I was trying to create login page, but there was a problem when I used set_userdata(). 
It doesn't work. When I checked, there was no session created. 
Is there any wrong with my code?? Any one has same problem with it??

```
function __construct(){
    $this->CI=&get_instance();
    $auth=$this->CI->config->item('auth');
    $this->CI->load->helper('cookie');
    $this->CI->load->library('session');
    $this->CI->load->model('Auth_users_model'); 
}

function login($username,$password){
    $result=$this->CI->Auth_users_model->get_login_info($username);
    if($result){
            $password=md5($password);
            if($password==$result->password){
                $user_ses=array('user_id_hcp'=>$result->id,'user_access_hcp'=>$result->access, 'user_username_hcp'=>$username);
                $this->CI->session->set_userdata($user_ses);
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what you are getting when print your $result. Do print_r($result); exit; in your controller and check

Comment: '$result' returns username and password from user table. I think there is no problem with this function, it returns TRUE, but session still not set... When it returns TRUE, page will be redirected to Dashboard, but it was redirected back to 'login page' because there is no session set..I think there is two possibilities: 1. set_userdata() doesn't work properly; 2. Session get lost after redirect

Answer (score -1):

Instead of $this->CI->session->set_userdata($user_ses);
try using simply
$this->session->set_userdata($user_ses);

Comment: That code is in library, so I use $this->ci->session->set_userdata(). I tried to create session with '$this->session->set_userdata()' in other page, but it still doesn't work. set_userdata() can't be used...